# Naming component props that are a list of options

Tags: reactjs, interface, components

What is considered the best practice for naming props that are a list of options.

On the example of Button with multiple variants:

1. Array of strings

   `variant: PropTypes.oneOf('primary', 'secondary')`
2. Each variant is a separate boolean

   `isPrimary: PropTypes.bool,
   isSecondary: PropTypes.bool,`
3. Each variant is a separate boolean, but prefixed

   `variantPrimary: PropTypes.bool,
   variantSecondary: PropTypes.bool,`

I've seen the first pattern many times, but autocomplete does not work in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider the first variant to be most useful. The reasons are:

1. you do not need to add another prop if you add a style
2. the people/co-workers using your component will get a more helpful error message when they use a wrong style telling them what options they can choose from
3. You can use the string provided to build the css class name to apply

On the other hand having a single prop is easier to use because you do not have to provide a value for a boolean prop:

```js
<Button primary>Click here</Button>
```